# Easiest way to add color to a title field?

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I have 2 fields, one is an image and the other is just a title. Now the title hovers above the image, but the problem here is that the image might clash with the font color. If the image is predominately white and the text is white, you wont be able to see it.

I was thinking of creating a new field just for the user to select white or black. Then i would create a tpl just for this article page to parse the "color" field and expose it for css styling. I feel like this is the long way to do this.

What other possible ways can this be accomplished?

Comment: There's a lot of "possible" ways it can be accomplished, but the idea you have sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not play with the styling? You can add text shadow or 50% dark transparent background to the text or add text outline as demoed here: http://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/ All these options will give you a better contrast.